# Failed at the project@0.0.0 ng script in Angular

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, angular-cli

I have updated my angular/cli version from 8 to 13 as my global angular/cli was greator than local
[image]

After updating angular cli i am unable to run the application it is throwing error
[image]

```
    {
   "name": "lio.documentreview.codingmodule.ui",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build:ssr": "ng run LIO.DocumentReview.CodingModule.UI:server:dev",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "-": "0.0.1",
    "@akveo/ng2-completer": "^9.0.1",
    "@angular/animations": "^8.2.12",
    "@angular/cdk": "~13.2.6",
    "@angular/common": "8.2.12",
    "@angular/compiler": "8.2.12",
    "@angular/core": "8.2.12",
    "@angular/forms": "8.2.12",
    "@angular/material": "~13.2.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "8.2.12",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "8.2.12",
    "@angular/platform-server": "8.2.12",
    "@angular/router": "8.2.12",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^5.2.3",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "8.1.1",
    "angular-6-datatable": "^0.8.0",
    "angular-font-awesome": "^3.1.2",
    "angular-progress-bar": "^1.0.11",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "core-js": "^3.3.3",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.2",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "ng-click-outside": "^6.0.0",
    "ng-multiselect-dropdown": "^0.2.10",
    "ng2-completer": "^9.0.1",
    "ng2-file-upload": "^1.4.0",
    "ng2-pdf-viewer": "^6.3.0",
    "ng4-loading-spinner": "^1.2.3",
    "oidc-client": "^1.9.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.6.7",
    "save": "^2.4.0",
    "sweetalert2": "^9.10.9",
    "xlsx": "^0.18.2",
    "zone.js": "0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.803.26",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^13.2.6",
    "@angular/cli": "^13.2.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.2.12",
    "@angular/language-service": "8.2.14",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.4.4",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.8",
    "@types/node": "~12.11.6",
    "codelyzer": "^5.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^4.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "typescript": "~3.4.5"
  },
  "optionalDependencies": {
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.2",
    "ts-node": "~8.4.1",
    "tslint": "~5.20.0"
  }
}
```

Can anyone please help me on this what i am missing? Before updating the local angular/cli application was running fine.

Answer (score 0):

you have a mismatch of package versions, which means, you can't have

@angular-devkit/build-angular: ^0.803.26

and

@angular-devkit/core: ^13.2.6

You should align all the packages versions to work